Kamailio enum module
I'm using Kamailio 5.7.x, and I need to perform enum queries using enum.so module. the enum.so module is confgured to use /etc/resolv.conf file to fetch dns server IPs, in my case I need to send to enum query to specific remote dns server that does not appear in /etc/resolv.conf and also to manage the timeout in case of the remote dns server is down or there is a network issue.
Is there any option on kamailio to override/overload the enum.so module? Or if someone has any suggestion? Thanks in advance.
Sending enum query to specific remote ip addresses and be able to manage a timeout in case of remote dns server is down or a network issue.
#
# load core modules
#
loadmodule "corex.so"
loadmodule "tm.so"
loadmodule "tmx.so"
loadmodule "sl.so"
loadmodule "async.so"

#
# load custom modules
#
loadmodule "custom_enum.so"

children=8

# create child processes for asynchronous tasks for "enum query" group
# because we have 3 remote dns servers each one has a response delay (e.g: the avg delay of server1 is 20ms, the server2 = 300ms ,...)
async_workers_group="name=enum_group_1;workers=8;nonblock=1;usleep=100"
async_workers_group="name=enum_group_2;workers=8;nonblock=1;usleep=100"
async_workers_group="name=enum_group_3;workers=8;nonblock=1;usleep=100"

request_route {

route(ROUTE1);
route(ROUTE2);
route(ROUTE3);
route(ROUTE4);

....

if(is_enum_query){
    if(server_name == "server1") {
        async_task_group_route("ENUM_ROUTE", "enum_group_1");
    } else if(server_name == "server2") {
        async_task_group_route("ENUM_ROUTE", "enum_group_2");
    } else {
        async_task_group_route("ENUM_ROUTE", "enum_group_3");
    }
} else {
    append_branch(contact);
    sl_send_reply("302", "Moved Temporarily");
}
exit;


}

route[ENUM_ROUTE] {

    #call custom module for sending enum
    $var(regex) = custom_enum(dns);
    ......
    append_branch(contact);
    send_reply("302", "Moved Temporarily");
}

route[ROUTE1] {
    # performing 1st lookup with postgresql   
}

route[ROUTE2] {
    # performing 2nd lookup with postgresql   
}

 route[ROUTE3] {
    # performing 3th lookup with postgresql   
}


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The module is using the libc dns functions which leverage the system resolver, therefore the query is done to the servers in the /etc/resolv.conf.
Some ideas for possible solutions:

use embedded Python interpreter (app_python3 or app_python3s module) to do the Enum query from a Python script using dnspython. A quick search on the web reveals it has support for custom DNS servers and e164 lookup. Ususally the target number for which one would want to do the Enum lookup is the R-URI username (Kamailio's $rU variable) and then use the result to build a new R-URI (Kamailio's $ru variable). Maybe something similar can be done with Lua (app_lua module) as well.

install a local DNS proxy that allows to direct queries to specific servers based on the domain (e.g., this dnsproxy project)

if C development is an option, then the enum module can be updated to use an alternative DNS library that has support for custom server (e.g., c-ares or adns)



Thanks @miconda for you answer. For the first solution using embedded Python, Can I run a script python inside kamailio native script?

You can load a Python script specified with modparam and then execute in routing blocks any method from it with  app_python3s_exec(...) - see: https://www.kamailio.org/docs/modules/stable/modules/app_python3s.html#app_python3.f.app_python3s_exec
